# Can a single socket be used for full duplex communication in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a peer-to-peer application where the connection between the two client peers must be duplex, so that both clients are capable of transmitting and receiving at the same time. Is it possible with a single socket or do I need to use two sockets?

Comment: Thank you for answer.Can you please elaborate how?If the client needs to transmit and receive at the same time, how one socket will do the job?

Comment: The question is operating system specific. The socket API is common to several OS

Answer (score 10):

It's possible; sockets on every OS I know of are full duplex - you can transmit and receive at the same time. However to achieve truly full duplex communication, you must ensure that your application can transmit while waiting to receive - this means either using non-blocking IO and event polling (On Linux there's `select` and `epoll`, or on windows things like `WSAAsyncSelect` or overlapping IO) or by using different threads for transmitting and receiving.

Comment: If I fork() a process and allow one process to transmit and the other to receive while using a single socket, will that work? I mean if two processes, one transmitting & one receiving, use the same socket, can it function as duplex?

Comment: That is another option, although in most cases using multiple processes to handle different directions on a socket adds more complexity than using an event-driven or multithreaded model, as you have to also consider how the two threads communicate with each other.

Comment: In response to the previous comment, I've seen code to the contrary. Having separate threads handle reading and writing can be much more straightforward than some of the single threaded solutions I've come across.